# Implement a multi level outline structure

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I need to setup and manage a multi level outline structure for requirements management in Microsoft Access 2013.

- outline needs to work much like a word outline where each record can have only 1 parent, but can have 1 or more siblings (sibling order does matter) and 0 to many children.
- Need to support as many outline levels as possible,  current data exceeds 15 levels but is being reduced where possible.
- need to be able to determine if a record has children,  has siblings, and what is its parent.
- need to be able to delete all children of a record when a record is deleted.
- need to be able to add new records either after or below a record in the outline structure
- need to be able to renumber the outline when adds, deletes, copies, and moves are done within the outline structure.

current approach is a table which contains a unique ID,  15 numeric fields for each individual level # of the outline #, and using a sort of the numeric fields to organize into the outline order.

running into several question related to this situation:

1. is this the best data structure approach or should I move outline info to a separate table?
2. given that I am in a query with an outline order sort,  can I write a VBA function as a calculated column to determine a record's parent, if it has siblings, and if it has children.
3. is it possible/practical to perform an sql select in vba to query the same table/query I am in to get a records parent, children, siblings, as a calculated column?
4. is it possible to use data triggers to support any management of this outline structure.

Example of the outline structure:

    `1
    1.1
    1.1.1
    1.1.2
    1.1.2.1
    1.1.2.2
    1.1.3
    2
    2.1
    2.2
    2.3
    2.3.1
    2.3.1.1
    2.3.1.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

This ain't going to be at all trivial in Access. For maximum flexibility in the number of levels I would not use separate fields for the level numbers but would instead have a self-referencing table with columns ID, NodeNumber, OutlineNumber, ParentID (NodeNumber would be a single number indicating which sibling this record is under a given parent - 1, 2, 3 - and OutlineNumber would be the full Outline reference for this record - 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3). You would use the ParentID to identify a record's parent; query all records with the same ParentID to find siblings; query records where the ParentID = current record's ID to find children. You're going to have to write some serious VBA code to control inserts, updates and deletes, and definitely don't let people add data manually into the table. Unfortunately Access does not have data triggers.

[EDIT] Apparently I'm wrong! Access does have an equivalent to SQL-Server "trigger" functionality called [data macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200), but I've never used it. Maybe this could help you?

Comment: Thanks for the information,  I agree that this is far from trivial.   I have seen an approach similar to what you describe used in an open source tool that we also use.   Unfortunately, that tool has a rep for corrupted outline structures, in fact, I already had to find and fix 2 bugs with its code related to this.    It doesn't invalidate the concept but illustrates how difficult this type of structure is to manage.    Unfortunately,  the constraints I am working within on this project have forced us to not try to manage the outline structure but leave that in the hands of users.